# Widgets get no update from the listener flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, notifications, widget, provider

I have implemented an listener in the following way:

```
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    final SlotDataProvider slotDevice = Provider.of<SlotDataProvider>(context);  
    spptask.streamdevice.listen((device) {
      setState(() {
        slotDevice._devices[0].name = device.name;
        print("Device data received: ${device.name} ");
      });
    }, onError: (error) {
      print("Error: $error.message");
    });

    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

I listen on a splitted controller and the print "Device data received:..." is called but the widget is not actualized. In the build method I do the following:

```
            ...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final slotProvider = Provider.of<SlotDataProvider>(context);
    final deviceProvider = Provider.of<DeviceDataProvider>(context);

    Device slotDevice = slotProvider.getDevice(widget.slot);
    Device device = deviceProvider.getDevice(widget.slot);

    _dropdownMenuItems = buildDropdownMenuItems(deviceProvider.get());
    return ListTile(
      title: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            width: 140,
            child: DropdownButton(
                isExpanded: true,
                disabledHint: Text(slotDevice.name),
                hint: Text(slotDevice.name),
                value: device,
                items: _dropdownMenuItems,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  device.setDevice(value);
                  slotDevice.setDevice(value);
                }),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 10),
          SizedBox(width: 60, child: Text('SLOT#${slotDevice.slot}')),
        ],
      ),
      subtitle: Text(slotDevice.bdaddr, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0)),
      leading: SizedBox(
        height: 40,
        width: 35,
        child: UsbBatteryImageAsset(slot: widget.slot),
      ),
      trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
    );
  }
}
```

What is missing in the above code. The SlotDataProvider is a fix list of "Device" with attributes such as name, id and so on.

@EDIT
The problem has to do with the combobox. If I change an other field, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Usually for widgets to be rebuilt based on the data updated we use streambuilders
this will cause the widget to rebuild every time there is a change in the stream 
it seams that your widget is being built once with the first listening of the data

have you tried wrapping the gridview in a stateful builder ?

Comment: This is not the only way we can do it. As I mentioned above it works but the problem is the Combobox.